# jquery ajax can see work when I debug step into the JS in FireFox, but does not work when I just let it run

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am really puzzled by this problem.   I am making a call to ASP MVC 5 controller. When I step through the code in FFox, I can clearly see that the breakpoint in the controller Action method DeleteBadItem is getting hit and the delete item process works fine.

However, if I don't step through the code in FFox, e.g.; not put a break in FFox next to $.ajax( line and step through there, the breakpoint in the controller Action method does not not get hit.   Instead, the Index method gets called and I see alert( "The request is complete!" ), but the break point in DeleteBadItem never get hits;

The controller return ActionResult so I am just putting alert for testing.

Any idea why the behavior works when I step through, but not otherwise?

thanks for the help

```
        var retVal = false;
        retVal = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
        var deleteString = [item1, item2]
        if (retVal) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("DeleteBadItem")",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(deleteString),
                success: function () {                       
                    location.reload();
                    alert("Record has been deleted");
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert("An error occured.  Record was not deleted.");
                },
                complete: function( xhr, status ) {
                    alert( "The request is complete!" );
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: step your code back one more level (in other words, show what is calling the code you have provided.)

Comment: Hi Kevin .... many thanks for the response.   You were right, there was a location.reload() call are the end of the $('.delete').on('click', function () { .... } event.   The intent of the reload is once the row in grid is deleted, I wanted to refresh the page (re-populate the grid).   The problem seems to be that the location.reload() was happening too soon.  I moved the location.reload() inside the complete: function( xhr, status ) {
                    alert( "The request is complete!" );
                } and this seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a comment by Kevin B "step your code back one more level (in other words, show what is calling the code you have provided.) ", I noticed that I was making a call to location.reload() at the end of the $('.delete') button click event, but out side the ajax block.   Moving this inside the ajax Complete block seems to solve the problem.